# How to compare the total values in one iteration against each record's value using Java StreamAPI?

Tags: java, loops, java-stream

I have Balance detail list in which I need to iterate over, accumulate the original value and compare that against each debt value in the list whiteout iterating over multiple times.

```java
BigDecimal cumulatetotamt= new BigDecimal(0);
BigDecimal thresholdRem= new BigDecimal(0);
```

**The first iteration:**

```java
for (Balance bal : BalanceList) {
    for (Adjustments adj: AdjustmentsReportList) {
        if (adj.getminval().equals(bal.thresholdval())) {
            cumulatetotamt = cumulatetotamt.add(bal.orginalval());
        }
    }
}
```

**The second iteration:**

```java
for (Balance bal : BalanceList) {
    for (Adjustments adj: AdjustmentsReportList) {
        thresholdRem = adj.val1().subtract(adj.val2());

        if (cumulatetotamt.compareTo(thresholdRem) > 0) {

        }
    }
}
```

My question is: How to achieve this task using a singe iteration with Java's Stream API?

Comment: Single iteration isn't possible. You're aggregating in one loop, to use as a cumulative amount in the other

Comment: but we are iterating it twice its a kind of code redundancy  how to iterate in efficient way

Comment: @user2302158 If you do this in one iteration, but you will not get the same answer, that is the point that OneCricketeer is saying. With the little information you have given us, it is currently IMPOSSIBLE to turn this into one loop without running the risk of giving you a wrong answer.

Comment: I don't think you can do the second iteration with streams at all. Subtraction is not [associative](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Associativity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it feasible to change it to something like this for the first time

```
BigDecimal totalBillAmt = BalanceList.stream()
                .flatMap(bal -> AdjustmentsReportList.stream()
                        .filter(adj -> adj.getBillCode().equals(bal.getSellQuotaNo()))
                        .map(Bill::getBillAmt))
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

What I mean is using map instead of looping once，second time;

Comment: How did you arrive at this solution where every method name is different to the names in the OP’s code?